# What is the exact difference among request.POST, request.data and request.GET in DRF?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Iam little bit confusion on request.POST,request.data And request.GET?
can anyone explain the main differences beween this In DjangoRestFramework views??

Answer (score 1):

`request.POST` and `request.GET` belong to [Django's `HttpRequest` object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.GET), they are `QueryDict` objects (a special kind of dicts that knows how to deal with multivalued keys), and are built from the querystring for a "get" request (`request.GET`)  or the request's "form-data" (more exactly: from the request's body, which must use the "form-data" encoding) for a "post" request (`request.POST`).

`request.data` belong to [DRF's own `HttpRequest` subclass](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/2-requests-and-responses/), is built fromrequest's content (which doesn't have to be form-data encoded), and is available for "post", "put" and "patch" requests.

Note that you could have just searched for those terms to find the relevant documentation (which is just what I did actually).

Comment: As an addition here's more information about `request.data`: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests/#data

Comment: Note that there's also `request.FILES` in Django, which contains the files submitted in a POST request, which must then use a "multipart/form-data" encoding.